# Combine two correlation statistics into one heatmap using ggplot geom_tile

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
dt <- data.frame(
  h = rep(LETTERS[1:5], 5), 
  j = c(rep("A", 5), rep("B", 5), rep("C", 5), rep("D", 5), rep("E", 5)),
  d1 = c(1, 0.717, 0.089, 0.027, 1, 0.717, 1, 0.11, 0.03, 1, 0.089, 0.11,
         1, 0.464, 0.835, 0.027, 0.03, 0.464, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.835, 1, 1), 
  r1 = c(1, 0.462, 0.002, 0.001, 0.001, 0.462, 1, 0.003, 0.001, 0.001, 0.002,
         0.003, 1, 0.054, 0.004, 0.001, 0.001, 0.054, 1, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.004, 0.001, 1)
)


# Heatmap using d1 as the input value
ggplot(dt, aes(x = h, y = j, fill = d1)) + 
  geom_tile(color = "black") +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "green") +
  geom_text(aes(label = d1), color = "black", size = 4) +
  coord_fixed() +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(x = "",
       y = "",
       fill = "D")

# Heatmap using r1 as the input value
ggplot(dt, aes(x = h, y = j, fill = r1)) + 
  geom_tile(color = "black") +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "red") +
  geom_text(aes(label = r1), color = "black", size = 4) +
  coord_fixed() +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(x = "",
       y = "",
       fill = "r")
```

For each of the heatmaps that I just made, half of the blocks are repeating the same information as the other half. Given that the axes are the same, I would like to combine the 2 heatmaps above into one that looks like the following - half is showing d1 values (using 1 color) and the other half is showing r1 values (using a different color). The diagonal blocks will be in color 3.
[image: Example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use multiple `geom_tile`s with appropriately filtered data and the `ggnewscale` package which allows to have multiple scales for the same aesthetic to color the lower and upper diagonal matrices differently:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)

# Add numeric row and column indices
dt <- transform(dt, row = as.numeric(factor(j)), 
                col = as.numeric(factor(h)))

size_border <- 2

ggplot(dt, aes(x = h, y = j)) + 
  # Diagonal
  geom_tile(data = ~ subset(.x, row == col), color = "white", fill = "purple", size = size_border) +
  geom_text(aes(label = d1), data = ~ subset(.x, row == col), color = "black", size = 4) +
  # Upper
  geom_tile(aes(fill = d1), data = ~ subset(.x, row > col), color = "white", size = size_border) +
  geom_text(aes(label = d1), data = ~ subset(.x, row > col), color = "black", size = 4) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "blue", limits = c(0, 1)) +
  # Lower
  new_scale_fill() +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = r1), data = ~ subset(.x, row < col), color = "white", size = size_border) +
  geom_text(aes(label = r1), data = ~ subset(.x, row < col), color = "black", size = 4) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "red", limits = c(0, 1)) +
  coord_fixed() +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(x = NULL,
       y = NULL)
```

[image]